# iOS8 Regional Localization (e.g. pt-BR)?

Tags: ios, localization, ios8, xcode6

From what I understand, iOS8 now supports regional localisations (in this case I want to support pt-BR).

See http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

I am having problems with this, testing this with a brand new single view application, in xcode I have added the pt and pt-BR languages to my project, and altered text accordingly in the pt.lproj and pt-BR.lproj directories.

After setting my device to pt-BR and running, the text displayed is always pt, not pt-BR as desired.

Indeed logging the preferred locale returned by NSLocale

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Locale = %@", language);
```

Returns only 'Locale = pt'...

Am I missing any steps or is this a bug in iOS8?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, iOS8 is using **pt** for **Portuguese Brasil** (instead of **pt_BR**). When you select **Portuguese Portugal**, the localization will be **pt_PT**

I've deleted the localization, and added the generic portuguese (and replaced with .strings files with the old ones).

Comment: It seems the only solution for now. "pt_BR" doesn't work as the locale identifier for Portuguese Brazil returns "pt_US".

Answer (score 2):

According to the apple docs a IETF BCP 47 should be returned. So you should get pt-BR if that's your preferred system language.

If what you want is only the current locale I suggest you use:

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]
```

Replace currentLocale with autoupdatingCurrentLocale if you want to support locale changes while your app is running.

EDIT: Locale is not the same as language ID! Sorry for misunderstanding. Anyway "pt" is the correct language ID for Brazilian portuguese:

> ... For example, use pt as the language ID for Portuguese as it is used in Brazil and pt-PT as the language ID for Portuguese as it is used in Portugal. The Other submenu (at the bottom of the list) contains more languages and dialects.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html

Comment: My language is definitely Portuguese (Brazilian) in the iOS preferences. Also, I'm less concerned with querying NSLocale and more with my localised files (xibs and strings) picking up the correct language...